# C++ Type conversion error /

Tags: c++, types

I need a function that checks whether the input value fits the variable (unsigned long long). And if it doesn't, the program should ask the user to input the value again (until a valid value is entered). I've tried that:

```
unsigned long long CheckInput()
{
    string input_st;
    cin>>input_st;
    for (int i = 0; i < input_st.length(); i++){
        if (input_st[i] >= '0' && input_st[i] <= '9');
        else { cout << "Error. Please try again  ";
            CheckInput();
        }
    }

    return stoull(input_st);
}
```

It doesn't work. The problem seems to be in stoull function, but how can I correct it? The compiler shows the error message "std::invalid_argument at memory location 0x0051F520" while running.

Comment: You are working on empty string all the time. Did you want to take it as a parameter?

Comment: recursion for error handling isn't such a good idea...

Comment: Why recurcion is bad? Anyway, the problem is different from that

Comment: Recursion is bad because a malicious user can cause stack overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had bothered to check the documentation for  `stoull()`, you would have found it throws a `std::invalid_argument` if the passed string cannot be converted to `unsigned long long`.

`input_st` in the code shown is always an empty string, which cannot be converted to an integral value, hence the thrown exception.

It is not the compiler showing the error message.   The error message being reported is a runtime error, resulting from the exception being thrown.

Unrelated to your question, if `input_st` somehow was a non-empty string that does not contain digits, the function would call itself recursively.   That is invalid logic.

Comment: I've tested the function with any numbers, just like 100, 500, 3300,etc., so I guess they can easily be converted from string to ULL.  That's why I don't know why it throws the exception. About the recursion - why do think that it is invalid?

Comment: The code, as posted, would not pass tests like you have described.

Comment: Obviously. That's why I'm here. So, do you have any ideas how to make the proper code for my descrpition?

Comment: Rewrite the function so it accepts input_st as a function argument, rather than declaring it as a variable inside the function (which creates input_st as an empty string every time the function is called).  Also, don't make the function recursive (i.e. don't have it calling itself).   Also, as said in the message about your question being "on hold", you need to provide COMPLETE code that exhibits your problem (i.e. both your function and the code that tests it).

Comment: "input_st in the code shown is always an empty string" -- No it isn't; it's read from cin. (Although apparently that was a later edit.) "the function would call itself recursively. That is invalid logic." -- No it isn't.

Comment: Yeah, right, Jim.  We both know that YOU edited the question and inserted an input statement AFTER I had replied, all so you have an excuse to tell me my logic is flawed.   This after you initiated a personal attack on me - and another member - in another topic.

Answer (score 1):

Also, at your code you are just checking if the string has only numbers.
You should also check if this number fits the unsigned long long. (2 to power 64)
[Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) you can find the maximum/minimum values for different types in C++.

Comment: I hadn't entered the numbers bigger than ULL max value, so the problem is somewhere else